# How to call a method if array.find() does not return anything?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am searching for element in array using array.find() like below:

```
this.selectedLib = libraries.find(lib => lib.name === 'Standard');
```

Now this method checks if any library has a name 'Standard' or not,
it sets `selectedLib` as Standard if it has  'Standard'.

But if there is no library with name Standard , I want to set library at index position 0 to be selectedLib.

something like this..:

```
lib.name=='Standard' ? lib : libraries[0]
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `this.selectedLib = libraries.find(lib => lib.name === 'Standard') || libraries[0];` ?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari tried this, not working

Comment: @MatteoTassinari sorry , I checked that... its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **find()** method returns a **value** in the array, if an element in the array
>   satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise **undefined** is
>   returned

.

```js
var libraries = [{
  name: "Not Standard",
  id: 1
}, {
  name: "Not Standard",
  id: 2
}]
var selectedLib = libraries.find(lib => lib.name === 'Standard') || libraries[0];
console.log(selectedLib);
```